# Remove node of single child parent in html agility pack

Tags: c#, .net, html-agility-pack

I'm using Html Agility Pack (1.4.9.5) to remove a node within a specified class:

```
var document = new HtmlDocument();
document.LoadHtml("<p><div class=\"remove-it\"></div></p>");

var nodesToRemove = document.QuerySelectorAll(".remove-it");
if (nodesToRemove != null)
{
    foreach (var node in nodesToRemove)
    {
        node.Remove();
    }
}

var res = document.DocumentNode.OuterHtml;
```

The problem is that at the end `res` is equal to:

```
<p>
```

but it should be:

```
<p></p>
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: What does `nodesToRemove` contain?

Comment: `nodesToRemove` contains only one node : the div in the paragraph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost there! You are missing 
`HtmlNode.ElementsFlags["p"] = HtmlElementFlag.Closed;` before `document.LoadHtml("<p><div class=\"remove-it\"></div></p>");`.

What that does is that the `p` element will be automatically closed when parsing the document.